# How can we delete commit history from protected branch in github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to remove historical commits to remove password from the code. How can we achieve this in a protected branch in github actions?

I tried bfg-repo cleaner but getting error that history can not be deleted for Protected branch.